# top align 2 divs of dynamic height within a containing div

Tags: css, html

I am trying to top-align two child divs in a containing div.  The child divs contain different content and may be of varying heights.  Is there a way I can make the two child divs top-align?

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/billafy/Rhj36/3/

> HTML

```
<div class="headerStuff">
    Header
</div>
<div class="sectionArea">
    <div class="leftPanel">
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="some image1" /></div>
        <div><button>test</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightPanel">
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="some image2" /></div>
        <div>
            <span>Some other text</span>
            <div>
                <span>And some additional content</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footerStuff">
    Footer
</div>
```

> CSS

```
    .headerStuff {
        font-size: 20pt;
        background-color: purple;
        border: 1px solid lime;    
    }
    .sectionArea {
        width: 100%; 
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 370px; 
        text-align: center; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid lime;
    }
    .leftPanel {
        display:inherit; 
        border: 1px solid orange;
    }
    .rightPanel {
        display:inherit; 
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .footerStuff {
        font-size: 20pt;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid lime;    
    }
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle seems to work... Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't need them centered then you can add float: left to both "Panels"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;` to both panels.

CSS:

```
.leftPanel {
    display:inherit; 
    border: 1px solid orange;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.rightPanel {
    display:inherit; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that does it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vertical-align:text-top;` in your right and left panels.